# How to create a form with a border, but no title bar? (like volume control on Windows 7)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7, windows-style-flags

In Windows 7, the volume mixer windows has a specific style, with a thick, transparent border, but no title bar. How do i recreate that window style in a winforms window?

[image: volume mixer]

I tried setting Text to string.Empty, and ControlBox to false, which removes the titlebar, but then the border also disappears:

[image: border disappears]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
form.Text = string.Empty;
form.ControlBox = false;
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
```

For a fixed size window, you should still use `FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow`, but you can override the form's `WndProc` to ignore non-client hit tests (which are used to switch to the sizing cursors):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;

    if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
        return;

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

If you want to really enforce the size, you could also set `MinimumSize` equal to `MaximumSize` on the form.

Comment: Nope, this removes the border completely

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow seems to work correctly for me.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: `FixedToolWindow` does remove the 3D border.  See my updated answer for getting fixed-size behavior with the 3D border intact.

Comment: I was trying to achieve this with `FixedSingle`. The solution for me from this answer was setting the form Text to empty.

Answer (score 1):

Since "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer." I present an edit to Chris' answer as a new answer.

The code his answer works as described - except that it also prevents any client area mouse event to occur. You need to return 1 (as in HTCLIENT) to fix that.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
    const int HTCLIENT = 0x01;

    if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        message.Result = new IntPtr(HTCLIENT);
        return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.