# create a form with formBorderStyle sizable and prevent resizing

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

Is it possible to create a form in C# that has formBorderStyle set to sizable but the user can't resize the form?

I know i can set the maximumSize and minimumSize to the same size and this will prevent resizing the form, but the cursor will still changes to resize when hovering over the border. And i don't want that.

I could use formBorderStyle = fixed but i am using sizable so the form looks like a windows 7 window. Is it possible to use "fixed" and apply some styles to the form so it looks like a sizable form (with the borders, transparency and the shade effect).

Thanks in for the reply's,

J.

EDIT:
Found the solution here:
[How to create a form with a border, but no title bar? (like volume control on Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594086/how-to-create-a-form-with-a-border-but-no-title-bar-like-volume-control-on-win)

Comment: Found the solution:

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594086/how-to-create-a-form-with-a-border-but-no-title-bar-like-volume-control-on-win

Answer (score 0):

Is `FixedSingle` not work for you? Forms are looking in the Windows 7 style too.

Comment: if i use FixedSingle or any other Fixed value, the form doesnt look like sizable, it has no borders, no transparency, no shader,..

Comment: Run it, don't just look at it in the designer.

Comment: i am running it, using visual studio 2010.