# How to fully hide the top bar in Windows Form using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controlbox

I am working in C#. I know that this question is commonly asked, it's just that I still cannot fully hide the top bar when I set the the form text string to be `""` and `controlbox = false`.

I still want the shadow effect:

[image: shadow effect]

The border on the side is gone and there is the usual shadow, but the top border has the odd white line that I remove.

The buttons on the upper right-hand side are generated by me and show the edge of my editable form. The white space above that is what I am trying to remove.

I do not want to set the form border property to `none` as I enjoy the integrated sizable controls and form shadow, so that is not an option.

Are there any other suggestions for this?

Comment: Did you try this: [How to create a form with a border, but no title bar? (like volume control on Windows 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594086/how-to-create-a-form-with-a-border-but-no-title-bar-like-volume-control-on-wi)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes I did, I actually read that before posting this. 
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow; I what I have set as my border, yet it still looks the same.

Comment: Hi. Got any luck on this one? I'm facing the same issue, tried many solutions with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I stumbled on to this problem and finally solved it so I'm posting it here for anyone that it can help.

So, I made a custom resizable borderless Form class with my own control bar and buttons, similar to the OP. The idea was to have that Form, with all the related `WndProc` code, act as the base class for all the other dialog forms in the project.

As I was running my project I was getting the exact same white line at the top of my form even though I had set all the appropriate form properties correctly.

The problem ended up being that with Form inheritance, all derived Forms also have their own private `InitializeComponent` method. I had no idea that the VS IDE set the FormBorderStyle property to `Sizable` in the derived Form class because my attention was only on the custom base class.

If you are using a custom base class for your `Form`, setting `FormBorderStyle` correctly in the **derived** class fixes the problem.

Comment: Can you help me with a sample? I can't get your idea.

Comment: While this appears to be a solution, it's not written well as an answer, it's written more as a comment. I'd recommend reading "[answer]" and its linked pages, then rewrite this more suscintly with some example code.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the Form, go to Properties to FormBorderSyle and put it in `False`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't set `FormBorderStyle` to `None` for a shadow, I already answered how to easily make shadows in "[Drop shadow on Borderless Winform-No flicker or disappearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913399/border-less-winform-form-shadow/60916421#60916421).
"
Here's my answer:

Try these steps and revert back if you have any errors:

1. Add this code to a new file named DropShadow.cs:

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Core
    {
        public class DropShadow
        {
            #region Shadowing

            #region Fields

            private bool _isAeroEnabled = false;
            private bool _isDraggingEnabled = false;
            private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
            private const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
            private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
            private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
            private const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x8;
            private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;
            private const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x0085;
            private const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;

            #endregion

            #region Structures

            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public struct MARGINS
            {
                public int leftWidth;
                public int rightWidth;
                public int topHeight;
                public int bottomHeight;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Methods

            #region Public

            [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMarInset);

            [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref int attrValue, int attrSize);

            [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public static extern int DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref int pfEnabled);

            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public static bool IsCompositionEnabled()
            {
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6) return false;

                bool enabled;
                DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out enabled);

                return enabled;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Private

            [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
            private static extern int DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out bool enabled);

            [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
            private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
            (
                int nLeftRect,
                int nTopRect,
                int nRightRect,
                int nBottomRect,
                int nWidthEllipse,
                int nHeightEllipse
            );

            private bool CheckIfAeroIsEnabled()
            {
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
                {
                    int enabled = 0;
                    DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref enabled);

                    return (enabled == 1) ? true : false;
                }
                return false;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Overrides

            public void ApplyShadows(Form form)
            {
                var v = 2;

                DwmSetWindowAttribute(form.Handle, 2, ref v, 4);

                MARGINS margins = new MARGINS()
                {
                    bottomHeight = 1,
                    leftWidth = 0,
                    rightWidth = 0,
                    topHeight = 0
                };

                DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(form.Handle, ref margins);
            }

            #endregion

            #endregion

            #endregion
        }
    }
   ```
2. In your form, add this line below `InitializeComponent()`:

   ```
    (new Core.DropShadow()).ApplyShadows(this);
   ```