# Windows Forms Colored, Bordered, Resizable, Titlebarless Window

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

The code below produces this, which has a remnant of a title bar at the top of it:

[image: Styling problem demonstration.]

The styling options were investigated in C++ using the Windows API as well, but the same results were achieved. There are other StackOverflow questions (e.g. [How to create a form with a border, but no title bar? (like volume control on Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594086/how-to-create-a-form-with-a-border-but-no-title-bar-like-volume-control-on-wi/3594119)) that reference these same options. The corresponding options for the WinAPI calls are `WS_BORDER | WS_THICKFRAME` passed to `GWL_STYLE` via `SetWindowLongPtr`.

I have also investigated the DWM API and the call `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` with a negative margin in the structure passed as its argument, however the negative value seems to invoke special treatment of the window and black areas are made transparent. The border is not drawn as I would like it to be.

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StylesTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Text = String.Empty;
            BackColor = Color.Black;
            ControlBox = false;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
            const int HTCLIENT  = 0x01;
            const int HTCAPTION = 0x02;

            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && (int)m.Result == HTCLIENT)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(HTCAPTION);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: The title contains what I wish to achieve, and the body of the post how I have tried to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following code you will get this result:

[image]

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StylesTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Text = String.Empty;
            BackColor = Color.Black;
            ControlBox = false;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
            const int HTCLIENT  = 0x01;
            const int HTCAPTION = 0x02;

            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && (int)m.Result == HTCLIENT)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(HTCAPTION);
        }
    }
}
```

- On the image is a white border but the form itself doesn't have that.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell what you have changed

Comment: My fault. Still had your code in my clipboard... Fixed it now. You just need to change the FormBorderStyle.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention it needs to be resizable. Adding resizability back in is what causes the title bar to appear. I hope to avoid drawing form elements myself, as it would be hard to support multiple Windows versions.